# Is it possible to use SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest while saving the audio to a file?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition

Is there any way to use speech recognition on audio captured from the device's microphone, while simultaneously saving this audio to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I didn't know why I didn't test it before asking, but simply following official documentation for audio recording and speech recognition, and running them both at the same time, works.